# Changing selection colors based on text and background color

Tags: html, css, selection, background-color, textcolor

I would like to change the ::selection color for both text and background on different parts of the website, based on the unselected text and background color. For example, I would like white text on dark background — when highlighted — to become dark text on light background, and vice versa (ideally I would be able to have many different colors I could use for different parts

I can successfully change the selection background and text color on most browsers using a single line of code I found elsewhere on this site, but couldn't find something that works for this, especially at my rudimentary skill level.

N.B. I am using Cargo Collective so I have limited access to the site's html and css panels (I can use global html and css globally and page by page). I am using many different shades of grey on the website, as opposed to a light and dark text and background, if that changes anything.

P.S. I apologize if this question is stupid and/or uses incorrect terms. Thanks for any and all help!

This is the code that looks really nice so far. The site's main background is that #939393, so this looks really clean as only the text color changes. However, there are pages with a different background and different color text, sometimes close to the inversion of these colors.

```
::selection {
    background: #939393;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to define your background colors and text colors as variables at the beginning of every css file, and replace property values with those variables, you could set it up to always swap text and background color for that page in a way that is very easy to maintain.

sample:

```css
:root {
  --bgred: 147;
  --bggreen: 147;
  --bgblue: 147;
  --tred: 30;
  --tgreen: 30;
  --tblue: 30;
}
body {
  background-color: rgb(var(--bgred), var(--bggreen), var(--bgblue));
  color: rgb(var(--tred), var(--tgreen), var(--tblue));
}
::selection {
  background-color: rgb(var(--tred), var(--tgreen), var(--tblue));
  color: rgb(var(--bgred), var(--bggreen), var(--bgblue));
}
```

```html
    <p>Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text.
    </p>
```

Sample 2

```css
:root {
  --bgred: 255;
  --bggreen: 127;
  --bgblue: 0;
  --tred: 0;
  --tgreen: 0;
  --tblue: 100;
}
body {
  background-color: rgb(var(--bgred), var(--bggreen), var(--bgblue));
  color: rgb(var(--tred), var(--tgreen), var(--tblue));
}
::selection {
  background-color: rgb(var(--tred), var(--tgreen), var(--tblue));
  color: rgb(var(--bgred), var(--bggreen), var(--bgblue));
}
```

```html
    <p>Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text. Select some text.
    </p>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for responding so quickly! Again, please excuse my total lack of understanding of these things: in this example and on my website, I am only seeing the text and background become grey and black, respectively. What am I missing to make this happen with different colors?

Comment: I've added Sample 2 to show that you can change the rgb color values at the start of the css without changing anything else in the css because the rest of the css has these variables in place of the typical red, green, and blue color values.